# Openquery performance with different number of columns

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, openquery

I have a query that uses openquery and takes too long time.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,
'SELECT column1, column2, column3, ..., column50
FROM someTable'
)
```

So it takes more than an hour.
However, I noticed that if I select only one column it takes just one minute:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,
'SELECT column1
FROM someTable'
)
```

So obviously it depends on the number of columns that I select.
The question is how to make faster the query with 50 columns?

**UPDATE:**

I still have the issue so I want to add a couple of details.

1. In my real query I do have the WHERE filter, but I didn't mention it in my question because I'm sure it doesn't matter.
2. The queries works much faster if I run them directly on the remote server.
3. It doesn't look as a channel issue since when I try to execute a multiple same queries in parallel they complete in the same time as a single query.
4. From my point of view it looks like there is an issue with driver or something like this.

Comment: Faster network speed? Select less rows? You're asking the remote server to *scan* the entire table, and then send that to the other server, which will likely need to write said data to a work table, to then send to your client; that's going to be slower than a normal query.

Comment: @ThomA I have asked to check our system administrator what happens with the network channel. He answered that it's free and he doesn't see any bad.

Comment: @ThomA sorry, I didn't mention it in my question (in order to make the example simpler), but in my real query I do have the WHERE statement and I use some filters to don't select all table rows.

Comment: So how many rows *are* being returned? Do you actually need all 50 columns?

Comment: @ThomA it returns about 50k rows (the whole table has a few billions rows) and yes, I do need all the 50 columns.

Comment: Also even if you have filters that won't necessarily speed anything up... if your filters aren't supported by a suitable index, you'll still have to scan the entire table to pluck those 50K rows (or seek and perform 50,000 lookups), then send 50K X 50 columns wide across the network. When you just select one column maybe it's faster both because you're sending 50K X _1_ column and also maybe using better indexes on the other side.

Comment: Are you doing this in Management Studio? Rendering 50K * 50 columns? SSMS has to render 2.5 million values in a grid. This also takes time. Try once with the option `Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid > Discard results after execution` ... but also don't render this much data in SSMS. What could you possibly do with it there? You should test this query from the application that will consume the data (and really reconsider what it can do with 50K rows too).

Comment: @AaronBertrand forget about the filters (that's not the thing). Imagine I have two queries with the same filters: 1st selects one column and 2nd selects 50 column. So the question is how to speed up the 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, I know, but still the plan will be much simpler when you only need to return one column vs. all 50. You said "but my query has filters!" and I said "those probably won't help!" (e.g. `SELECT TOP (50000)` with no `ORDER BY` will perform similarly) and you said "forget about the filters!" ... I think we're saying the same thing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand :) that's why I didn't mention filters in my initial question because I'm sure the filters don't matter in my case. I mentioned the filters later because ThomA asked about them in his answer. Anyway I believe we understood each other.

Comment: @AaronBertrand actually I also tried to insert the results into #tempTable to avoid the render but it still took the same long time.

Comment: Then the only thing left is network (other than an underpowered linked server that can't give you data fast enough - did you try running the query locally on `linkedserver`?), so I have little faith in `He answered that it's free and he doesn't see any bad.` What happens if you copy large files between these two servers? Are they fast? Slow? How about backing up to (or restoring from) the other server's disk? What Mb/s do you get there? (This is not a measure of _just_ network performance, but it can help isolate the issue more than a linked server query alone.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand well, it's always like this with system admins :) They are looking into their staff, telling you that everything is okay there and you only have to trust. Actually there is no way for me to check anything of this.

Comment: Generally, linked servers are garbage, anyway. If this is something you're going to be doing regularly, instead of relying on some linked server I'd just create an AG secondary or transactional replication to always have an up-to-date copy on the consumer server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the number of columns, but their cumulative size. You have at least one very large-sized column in your query, if the filter that you have is the same in both cases.

So, you will need to figure out which column is the big one, by looking at the way your table was defined in the first place. Try running the query with one column at a time and do this for all your columns. This will allow you to find out what column's writing is the slowest.

Now, if you have this kind of extremely large column values, you will need to figure out whether you need that column. If not, then you can simply remove it from the query and it should execute in a much quicker pace. If you need the column(s) that slow down the query, then you will either accept that the query takes a long while to execute, or separate the slow columns from the query. You may execute the query without the large columns and then execute the slow-part of your query separately, possibly via packet runs.

So, if you want some quick early results, then you can omit the large columns from the query and have a long-running job later that gets those values. So, your long texts and binary large objects will get later into the target, but username and email is there quickly.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer. The thing is that I have checked all my columns using something like SUM(LEN(column1)), SUM(LEN(column2)), ... and I didn't find any column with abnormal size. Actually it close to direct dependence: 50 columns in select takes T minutes, 25 columns - T/25, 1 column - T/50 (of course it's approximately).

Comment: @chaika_sv happy to help. I would test loading the actual values of the columns instead of cumulative length. It might not look too lengthy when you sum its length, but loading the actual values contributes to a real test